# create git pull -f multi-token alias

Tags: bash

I'd like to make an alias like this:

`'git pull -f'='MYBRANCH="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"; echo "origin/${MYBRANCH}" | git reset --hard'`

In simpler terms, it's a `git reset --hard origin/my_current_branch`.

But bash tells me that `git pull -f` cannot be a valid alias (probably because there are spaces in it?). Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Can you post what you have you in your .bashrc?

Comment: I just have the line `alias 'git pull -f'=[insert that mess]` in my .bash_profile

Comment: Yes; choose a valid name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to perform the following steps with the alias:

- Get the name of your current branch
- Fetch the corresponding branch from `origin`
- Hard-reset to the remote branch

Instead of a Bash alias to do this,
I suggest to define a Git alias.
To do that, add this in the `[alias]` section in your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
myreset = "!f() { br=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD); git fetch origin $br; git reset --hard origin/$br; }; f"
```

This way, you can run `git myreset` to perform the operations.
(Feel free to rename "myreset" to whatever you prefer.)